# Burst mode in iphone app using UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want Burst mode in my iPhone app like this application which is available on app store [FOTOR](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fotor-photobag/id503037128?mt=8). It means when i click on camera i can take more than one photos in one click and after that i will select one photo which is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check This Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)
By hiding all  Controls(picker.showsCameraControls = NO;) i can resolve my problem